# How to get single value from this multi-dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Example `print_r($myarray)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6578765
        [name] => John Smith
        [first_name] => John
        [last_name] => Smith
        [link] => http://www.example.com
        [gender] => male
        [email] => email@example.com
        [timezone] => 8
        [updated_time] => 2010-12-07T21:02:21+0000
    )
)
```

Question, how to get the `$myarray` in single value like:

```
echo $myarray['email'];  will show email@example.com
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "single format"?

Comment: I don't know how to call it. but from the array i want to get the data one by one.

Comment: echo $myarray['email'] DOES show email@domain.com, a single value. It is not clear what you're asking!

Comment: @Dan Grossman LOL Okay let's me make example. `$myarray` from this array how do I get the output for `first_name`, `gender` or etc.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Look at the keys and indentation in your `print_r`:

```
echo $myarray[0]['email'];

echo $myarray[0]['gender'];
```

...etc

Comment: I can echo a key in the following way but only on my local instance: `echo myarray()["baseurl"];` when I push to a remote server, I get a parse / syntax error. Why is that?

Comment: @MichelJoanisse probably because you are using an older PHP version on your remote server. That syntax is not supported in PHP <5.4 (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102).

Answer (score 46):

Use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) function

```
$myarray = array_shift($myarray);
```

This will move array elements one level up and you can access any array element without using `[0]` key

```
echo $myarray['email'];
```

will show `email@example.com`

Answer (score 22):

I think you want this:

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key = $value\n";
}
```

Comment: yes! this one. I got return `0 = Array` but when I `print_r($myarray)` showing the output.

Comment: Got it by put `$myarray[0]`. Thanks make me learnt a new thing :P

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `array_column()`. It's available from PHP 5.5: [php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

It returns the values from a single column of the array, identified by the column_key. Optionally, you may provide an index_key to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column in the input array.

```
print_r(array_column($myarray, 'email'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The first element of `$myarray` is the array of values you want. So, right now,

```
echo $myarray[0]['email']; // This outputs 'email@example.com'
```

If you want that array to become `$myarray`, then you just have to do

```
$myarray = $myarray[0];
```

Now, `$myarray['email']` etc. will output as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $myarray[0]->['email'];
```

Try this only if it you are passing the `stdclass object`

Comment: Could you give more context to the original poster? Like explain what is not working in his code and how the suggested change will fix it. And maybe detail what is `stdclass object`.

Comment: he is getting 2d array ,  and wants a first value of 2d array . So if he is passing his object from controller to view , like in Laravel (MVC framework), 
his views get stdclass object. And from that stdclass object , if a person wants single value , he can print his value as i mentioned above .
For more stdclass objects in php link :http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: This definitely doesn't work. https://3v4l.org/VRo2O