# Php - get array value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get value from an array like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => May 2019 1
    [1] => May 2019 14
)
```

I need to get just  1 and 14 from this array
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @pc-shooter I think what he means it "*I want to extract the last number of every item in this array*". That'd be `1` and `14`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo but still 43'892 results... and no help? I mean, have a look at the answers, familiary, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$arr = array('your array');
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $date = end(explode(' ',$v));
    //do your stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) , [`array_pop()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$dates = array_map(function ($v){
    $v = explode(' ',$v); //<--- Explodes your array using a space
    return array_pop($v); //<--- Grabs the last element and returns to your $dates array.
},$yourarray);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/148131)</kbd>

Comment: Looking at the OP's question and your answer, I don't think he will understand this. A combination of `array_map()` and `array_pop()` is harder to understand and read than for example a `foreach()` loop with the `end()` function.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*  ,

```
 $myarray    =   array('Monday, 06. May 2019 1','Sunday, 19. May 2019 14');

 foreach($myarray as $str){
     $split = explode(" ", $str);
     echo $split[count($split)-1].'</br>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by @pc-shooter this has been answered loads already, a quick Google gives the answer too.
[how-to-get-single-value-from-php-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383914/how-to-get-single-value-from-php-array)

`echo $array[1].$array[14];`

Comment: Not what he asked, though. This would give you `Sunday, 19. May 2019 14` and an undefined index notice.

Comment: So why you answer it then?

Comment: h2oooooo ok yeah i'm wrong :/

PC-shooter just because, I'm trying to get more rep so I can up-vote answers I find helpful when researching myself. I have used Stack for years to help me but never been able to up-vote as a thanks. (never needed to ask a question though, always find what I'm after through searches)

Comment: @CygnusH33L Ok I must admit, I did that too