# handling json data with php

Tags: php, json

My json data is:

```
{"jsondata":[[1,7,16,29,41,45],[2,12,21,31,36,45]]}
```

There are 2 sets of numbers and each set has 6 different number. And the number of total **sets** can be more according to user's input. So, there may be 3 sets which means 18 numbers, etc. If I copy/paste that in to http://json.parser.online.fr/ , I see no error. So, json data is correct, **I guess**.

Second, here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$result=json_decode($input);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

That works fine too. I mean, when I run these lines, in the chrome's developer tool, I can see these:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["jsondata"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(7)
      [2]=>
      int(16)
      [3]=>
      int(29)
      [4]=>
      int(41)
      [5]=>
      int(45)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
      [1]=>
      int(12)
      [2]=>
      int(21)
      [3]=>
      int(31)
      [4]=>
      int(36)
      [5]=>
      int(45)
    }
   }
  }
```

So far, I think, what I have to understand is json data is correct and php can respond it back. So, how can I reach this numbers and assing them into another variable in PHP? My actual aim is send them into the mysql. If I can get them, it is easy.

Some says use key/value pair thing but the problem is, my json data creates itself according to user's input. User clicks some numbers and then the number get appended into the json data. And it continues each of six clicks:

```
function createjson(){
var c=1;
var json='{"jsondata":[[';
$("#kup td").each(function(){
    if($(this).html()!="" && $(this).html()!="SELECTED NUMBERS")
    {
        json+= parseInt($(this).html())+',';
        if($(this).index()%5==0 && $(this).index()!=0) //sixth number selected
        {
            json=json.substring(0,json.length-1);                       
            json+="],["
        }                       
    }               
});
json=json.substring(0,json.length-3);
json+="]]}";
return json;
};
```

I thought I found my answer [here](http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP) but it didn't work either or I did somethings wrong. I am very newbie on these json stuffs, so please don't force me to change whole thing. There must be a way to reach this values. So, please save me guys :-)

Comment: You can reach them just as you would any other array values.

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you give an example syntax please? I really need this... Because I did everything I know with my PHP knowledge, but I am about the cry. I am serious :/

Comment: You show what you use to create the JSON. What have you tried to get values from the JSON? Here are some examples - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383914/how-to-get-single-value-from-php-array

Comment: @WhoCares Accessing array elements and object members is _really_ basic stuff. Reading a beginner's book or tutorial on PHP would probably be helpful for you. But for now, read the docs on [Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). (It will teach you how to access object members and array items, but also a bit more about them.)

Comment: Guys, you are right, there is an array, but where is it? I used `$result->array(0)`, `$result->array(0)(0)`, `$result['array(0)']`, `$result['array(0)(0)']`, I used `foreach ($result as $k => $v)` but there is nothing. just NULL.

Comment: Start with `$result[0]`

Comment: @JayBlanchard it returned error in chrome's dev. tool => "500"

Comment: Are you trying to get the values via JavaScript or PHP? If PHP, you cannot do that from the console.

Comment: I am trying to get these values in my PHP file. I tried what you said, and PHP file didn't respond back to ajax part. So I think there is an error occured, right? If you want, I can try to insert `result[0]` in to mysql? just to be sure?

Comment: I know @Carsten - I am trying to teach the OP how to fish, rather than catching, cleaning, frying and then serving them.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Okay, sorry. My lips are sealed. ;)

Comment: @Carsten I did yours and it returned `Array`. Then I did `$result->jsondata[0][0]`, it returned with the correct number. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No worries @Carsten - we can teach the OP to fish together :) And it appears that they caught something!

Comment: and what is this "OP" thing in this site? is it the question owner? :)

Comment: "OP" == Original Poster and/or Original Post

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode function with second parameter to convert JSON string into array:

```
$input = '{"jsondata":[[1,7,16,29,41,45],[2,12,21,31,36,45]]}';

$data = json_decode($input, TRUE);

var_dump($data['jsondata']);
```

In this case you should get associated  array that simply for using