# how to get one specific entry in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

this is the print_r of my array

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [displayorder] => 3 [menuname] => Accounting Module [menuurl] => [menuflag] => 1 [menuid] => 3 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [displayorder] => 4 [menuname] => My Profile [menuurl] => myprofile.php [menuflag] => 0 [menuid] => 4 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [displayorder] => 6 [menuname] => HR Module [menuurl] => [menuflag] => 1 [menuid] => 2 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [displayorder] => 9 [menuname] => Administrator [menuurl] => [menuflag] => 1 [menuid] => 1 ) )
```

I want to make a condition that when i have a `menuid` input it will get the `menuname` of the array of the `menuid`

found this solution:

`$myarray[0]['menuname'];` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383914/how-to-get-single-value-from-php-array)

but it only gets the `menuname` of the first array how can you make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function passing your multi array and menu id as parameter to it, to return desired value from your multi-array, like:

```
function getMenuNameById($yourArr, $menuId) {
    foreach($yourArr as $val) {
        if( $val["menuid"] == $menuId ) {
            return $val["menuname"];
        }
    }
}
//use it
$menuName = getMenuNameById($your_multi_arr, $menu_id);
```

Comment: i have one question because i need it to run inside a function is ok to run another function inside a function?how is it possible?

Comment: you can just call this function inside another function, you will have to pass your multi array and menu id as parameter to it.