# How do I get values of the email out of this array?

Tags: php

How do I get values of the email out of this array?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ExamApplication] => Array
            (
                [id] => 27
                [user_id] => 78
                [exam_id] => 2
                [faculty_id] => 3
                [subspeciality_id] => 0
                [ref_number] => 14490644320853527823
                [exam] => 
                [certification] => /files/78/2015-12-02-09-46-40-Dr._Taofeek.jpg
                [marriage_certificate] => 
                [newspaper_advert] => 
                [sworn_affidavit] => 
                [other_marriage_evidence] => 
                [primary_evidence_cert] => 
                [med_school] => LADOKE AKINTOLA UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY, OGBOMOSO, OYO STATE.
                [med_school_address] => P.M.B 4000, OGBOMOSO, OYO STATE
                [med_school_year] => 2013
                [med_school_cert] => 
                [med_school_cert_type] => 
                [med_board_year] => 7-11-2014
                [med_board_cert] => /files/78/2015-12-02-09-46-40-scan0014.jpg
                [med_board_cert_type] => 
                [discharge_year] => 3-11-2015
                [discharge_type] => NYSC
                [discharge_cert] => /files/78/2015-12-02-09-46-40-scan0012.jpg
                [discharge_cert_type] => 
                [training_cert] => 
                [accredition_prog_inst] => 
                [accredition_prog_add] => 
                [accredition_prog_year] => 
                [mbbs_cert] => /files/78/2015-12-02-09-46-40-scan0007.jpg
                [logbook] => 
                [excemption_cert] => 
                [manuscript_cert] => 
                [revision_cert] => 
                [surgeon_cert] => 
                [surgical_cert] => 
                [ethics_cert] => 
                [exam_date] => 04/2016
                [exam_center] => Ibadan
                [approval_status] => Approved
                [reseat_status] => No
                [save_status] => 3
                [submitted_date] => 
                [exam_number] => 20704160002
                [comment] => 
                [created] => 2015-12-02 09:46:40
                [modified] => 2016-02-22 14:25:12
            )

        [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 78
                [email] => tafabny@yahoo.com
                [password] => 81e1e0742e4e06c5a13e87000e3f8d201e51dc02
                [role] => students
                [faculty_id] => 0
                [status] => 1
                [pass_token] => 
                [created] => 2015-12-01 10:32:15
                [modified] => 2015-12-01 10:32:15
            )

        [Exam] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [init] => 1000
                [exam] => Primary
                [exam_months] => 10
                [exam_years] => 2016
                [closing] => 2016-08-17
                [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [modified] => 2016-04-23 12:33:54
            )
```

Please how can I get the value of the user email out from the above array?

Comment: Let `$arr` is your array, use this `echo $arr[0]['User']['email']`;

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can get your array value using below statement

```
echo $arr[0]['user']['email'];
```

For more details of array and value use below link 
[how to get single value from php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383914/how-to-get-single-value-from-php-array)

Comment: @ManthanDave, thanks for the answer, but the issue is that, I have lots of data to loop through, how can i make the [0] like a constant, because it is likely to reach [1000]